# How do I use a condition variable to wait for a thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, mutex, condition-variable

I am developing a server and the client is given.
it's a shared document and each time only one can write to the file.
every 10 second I want to "refresh" all the clients,
so all the clients will see what the client that can write wrote.
my code work with 2 clients but if I add 1 more it doent work

this is my code:

```
void Server::addNewClient(SOCKET sc)
{

    //get the client's name
    std::string name = Helper::getUsername(sc);

    //new thread
    std::thread newClient(&Server::connection, this, sc, name);


    //get next writer
    next = clientDeque.size() > 1 ? clientDeque[1] : "no next";

    //send Message 101 
    Helper::sendUpdateMessage(sc, fileContent, clientDeque[0], next, getPosition(name));

    newClient.detach();

}
```

the connection function:

```
while (code != 208)
{
    //read only 
    while (name != clientDeque[0])
    {
        writeToServer(sc, name);
    }
   //""" same more code"""
   readFromServer(sc, name, code);
```

the writeToServerfunction:

```
void Server::writeToServer(SOCKET sc, std::string name)
{
    cond.wait(_lock);

    try {
    Helper::sendUpdateMessage(sc, fileContent, clientDeque[0], next, getPosition(name));
    }
    catch (std::exception& ex)
    {
          std::cout << ex.what() << std::endl;
    }
}
```

and in the readFromServer function  i have

cond.notify_all();

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Where do you acquire lock before waiting on it? Post a [mcve]

Comment: In the constructor, maybe it's the problem?